# next.js image is missing src property

Tags: reactjs, svg, next.js, tailwind-css, next-images

I get this error:

> error : image is missing src property.

I'm not sure what's wrong since it worked with code I have. After I closed vscode and opened it again shortly the error happened. Here's my codes:

**navbar.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";
import Logo from "../components/svg_logo.svg";

export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <nav className="bg-transparent">
      <div className="max-w-6xl mx-auto px-4 pt-1.5">
        <div className="flex justify-between">
          <div className="flex space-x-4">
            <div>
              <Link href="#">
                <a className="flex items-center py-5 px-2 select-none text-gray-700 text-2xl hover:text-gray-900">
                  <Image src={Logo} alt="logo" height={30} width={30} />
                  <span className="font-bold text-white">Logo</span>
                </a>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

*next-config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,

  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ["@svgr/webpack"]
    });

    return config;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think optimizing an SVG image is needed. and if you need to make this done put the Image svg asset on the public folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted the `webpack config` from `next.config.js` settings that are not necessary.You can display your **logo** `svg` in two ways, directly from `Image src` or `import` from `Logo`, both work fine, like this:

**example.js**

```
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";
import Logo from "../public/images/nextjs.svg";

function ExamplePage() {
  return (
    <nav className="bg-green-600">
      <div className="max-w-6xl mx-auto px-4 pt-1.5">
        <div className="flex justify-between">
          <div className="flex space-x-4">
            <div>
              <Link href="#">
                <a className="flex items-center py-5 px-2 select-none text-gray-700 text-2xl hover:text-gray-900">
                  <Image
                    // src="/images/nextjs.svg"
                    src={Logo}
                    alt="logo"
                    height={60}
                    width={60}
                  />
                  <span className="font-bold text-white">Logo</span>
                </a>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default ExamplePage;
```

---

**next.config.js** I removed `webpack(config)`

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
};
```

---

Project Folder & File structure:

[image]

---

Output:

[image]

*Tested with "next": "12.0.7","react": "17.0.2", "tailwindcss": "^3.0.5"*

Comment: Thank you again! You're a true life saver!

Comment: @QI10 The pleasure is all mine ! You're welcome ;-) Best regards !